# Package Manager for VS2012 does not display packages in local feed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, backwards-compatibility

I've created a simple package, only consisting of a couple of binaries in the 
`tools` folder. The package is created with NuGet version 4.4.1.4656.

A local folder has been initialized with `nuget init` and contains said package. VS2017 Package Manager shows the package as expected, whereas VS2012 does not.

There are no available updates for the Package Manager in VS2012, which is at version 2.8.60318.667.

How do I get the feed to work with VS2012, so I can install the package in one of our older solutions? Is this a compatibilty issue?

Any pointers are welcome!

Comment: try updating the Package Manager

Comment: To quote myself: "There are no available updates for the Package Manager in VS2012, which is at version 2.8.60318.667." :)